# Как упорядоченно вывести максимумы списка по убыванию

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть задача: нужно вывести максимумы в списке, который генерируется ГПСЧ. Сделать это нужно в порядке по убыванию. 
Например

```
x = {105,150,501}
```

Output:

```
1: 501
2: 150
3: 105
```

Я написал код, но он ищет только самый максимальный элемент. Мне нужно найти второй, третий, n-нный...
Подозреваю, что мне нужно перебирать элементы в цикле for, но я не понимаю, как правильно это реализовать.

```
import random
spisok = []

for i in range(0,5):
    spisok.append(random.randint(1,3))


maxi = max(spisok)

print('Сгенерированы такие числа: ')
print(spisok)
print('Максимальный элемент списка: ')
print(maxi)
```

Comment: Чем задача отличается просто от сортировки списка по убыванию?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как вывести элементы списка по убыванию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059205/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [12]: {k: v for k, v in enumerate(sorted({105, 150, 501}, reverse=True), start=1)}
Out[12]: {1: 501, 2: 150, 3: 105}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

spisok = []

for i in range(0,5):
    spisok.append(random.randint(1,3))

maxi = max(spisok)

a = sorted(spisok, reverse=True)

print('Сгенерированы такие числа: ')
print(a)
print('Максимальный элемент списка: ')
print(maxi)
```

P.S. Oбновил вывод сгенерированных чисел (`print(a)`).

Comment: Да, это работает. Но мне нужно чтобы элементы не только сортировались, но ещё и выводились.
Например: 
x = {105,150,501}

А выводится:
1: 501 2: 150 3: 105

Comment: по порядку или от возрастания? x = {5,3,1}?

Comment: По убыванию. От самого большого - к самому маленькому :)