# Как вывести элементы списка по убыванию

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код. Генерируется 6 чисел, дальше они сортируются по убыванию. 
В этом коде есть цикл (самый последний), в этом цикле должны выводиться максимумы.
Т.е., должен находиться первый максимум (самая большая цифра) и выводиться, дальше второй - и выводиться, третий и.т.д. Проблема в том, что цикл не работает так, как это мне нужно. Что можно с этим сделать? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
import random

spisok = []

for i in range(0,5):
    spisok.append(random.randint(1,3))

maxi = max(spisok)

a = sorted(spisok, reverse=True)

print('Сгенерированы такие числа: ')
print(a)
print('В порядке убывания: ')
print(a)

for i in range(spisok[i-1]):
    for j in range(spisok[i+1]):
        if spisok[i] == spisok[j]:
            print('{cout} максимум: {maxim}'.format(maxim = spisok[i], cout = i))
            continue
```

Comment: Не нужно двух вложенных циклов. У вас список отсортирован по убыванию - значит первым идет первый максимум, потом второй максимум, и т.д. Нужно просто последовательно пройти по списку. И сгенерированные числа имеет смысл выводить до сортировки, а то два раза одно и то же выводится.

Comment: А `i` тут откуда возьмется `spisok[i-1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for num, i in enumerate(a, 1):
    print('{cout} максимум: {maxim}'.format(maxim = max(a), cout = num))
    a.remove(max(a))
```

вывод:

```
Сгенерированы такие числа: 
[3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
В порядке убывания: 
[3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
1 максимум: 3
2 максимум: 3
3 максимум: 2
```

Если нужно все одинаковые цифры убирать, то добавляем еще такой цикл

```
for num, i in enumerate(a, 1):
    print('{cout} максимум: {maxim}'.format(maxim = max(a), cout = num))
    m = max(a)
    while m in a:
        a.remove(m)
```

вывод:

```
[3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
1 максимум: 3
2 максимум: 2  # - не считает вторую тройку еще раз
```

Answer (score 2):

Первая часть это генерация и сортировка:

```
import random

nums = [random.randint(1, 3) for i in range(5)]

print('Сгенерированы такие числа: ')
print(nums)

sorted_nums = sorted(nums, reverse=True)
print('В порядке убывания: ')
print(sorted_nums)
```

Варианты решения:

**1. Через `groupby`.** Метод `groupby` сгруппирует подряд идущие элементы в последовательности:

```
from itertools import groupby
...

for i, (num, _) in enumerate(groupby(sorted_nums), 1):
    print('{i} максимум: {maxim}'.format(i=i, maxim=num))
```

**2. Через цикл.** Первый элемент выводим и запоминаем, а в цикле начинаем со второго элемента с проверкой предыдущего:

```
i = 1
last_num = sorted_nums[0]
print('{i} максимум: {maxim}'.format(i=i, maxim=last_num))

for j in range(1, len(sorted_nums)):
    num = sorted_nums[j]
    if num != last_num:
        i += 1
        print('{i} максимум: {maxim}'.format(i=i, maxim=num))

    last_num = num
```

**3. Через множество.** Это множество удалит дубликаты, но потребуется создание новой коллекции, поэтому может быть затратным:

```
sorted_nums = sorted(set(sorted_nums), reverse=True)

for i, num in enumerate(sorted_nums, 1):
    print('{i} максимум: {maxim}'.format(i=i, maxim=num))
```

Конечно, тут лучше всего `nums` в множество помещать, т.е. не делать лишней предварительной сортировки:

```
nums = [random.randint(1, 3) for i in range(5)]
...
sorted_nums = sorted(set(nums), reverse=True)
```